# Interesting examples of large, accessible, non-presentable $\infty$-categories?

Tags: homotopy-theory, higher-category-theory, infinity-categories, derived-algebraic-geometry, higher-algebra

> **What are some interesting examples of accessible $\infty$-categories
>   which are not presentable and not small?**

By interesting I mean a category which comes up naturally in a certain context and in a way which doesn't allow working around it.

I prefer examples from derived algebraic geometry as these will most likely be more understandable to me but any interesting example will do.

**Edit:** As Dimitri pointed out in a comment **there are already examples in ordinary categories** (e.g. the category of fields). To focus my question I'd like to add the restriction that **the category should not be $1$-truncated.**

Comment: The category of fields.

Comment: Flat modules over a commutative ring spectrum?

Comment: @CharlesRezk I don't know much about ring spectra but Is there a context in which one is forced to work and preform constructions exclusively in this category? Can't one just embed into all modules and study them there?

Comment: @SaalHardali sure. Actually, I'm pretty sure you can embed any accessible $\infty$-category fully inside a presentable one.

Comment: @SaalHardali, looking at HTT, it appears that's true by definition.

Comment: @CharlesRezk If what you say is true + this embedding preserves all filtered colimits + the embedding is dense (the ambient presentable category is generated under finite colimits from the accessible subcategory) then this question wouldn't be interesting to me anymore. My main motivation is to understand whether there are $\infty$-categories which are seriously studied  yet have no clear connection with model categories.

Comment: @SaalHardali To answer you last question: yes there are ∞-categories that are best studied on their own terms (although you *can* use model category techniques to study any ∞-category this is sometimes unwieldy). An example I am fond of is the Burnside category of a finite group.

Comment: @DenisNardin "...you can use model category techniques to study any $\infty$-category" maybe I'm looking for the strongest precise statement one can make in this regard...

Comment: @SaalHardali Pretty much any type of ∞-category can be embedded (for various definitions of the word embed) into a presentable ∞-category and presentable ∞-categories have presentations by combinatorial model categories? Although I meant it more as an heuristic than as a theorem.

Comment: @DenisNardin Unless you know some things about this embedding this seems not very useful to me. I mentioned some properties which would completely convince me of this heuristic. If these are not satisfied then I don't really understand why this is a good heuristic. Of course any ordinary category can be embedded into a presheaf category so any category can be studied using presheaves (this doesn't really work in practice - unless it does in which case I'm here to be enlightened).

Comment: I think we shouldn't have this discussion in the comments (it is getting too long), but I do not understand what kind of application you have in mind. For example, as Charles Rezk already told you, every accessible ∞-category embeds into a presentable ∞-category via an accessible functor.

Comment: I would very much like to know in what sense "pretty much any type of $\infty$-category can be embedded into a presentable $\infty$-category." I find this statement very hard to believe. The way I see it, most model categories are not combinatorial, and this is a restrictive hypothesis. When I try to read $\infty$-categorical work, it often comes down to assuming things are presentable, which seems an equivalently restrictive hypothesis. This is my main concern about working with $\infty$-categories.

Comment: @DavidWhite The precise statement depends on what kind of "embedding" you are looking for. At the minimum every ∞-category $C$ has the Yoneda embedding into the category of presheaves $\mathrm{Fun}(C^{op},\mathrm{Spaces})$, which is presentable. If add hypotheses to your category you get to preserve more structure with the embedding.

Comment: @DavidWhite Also (sorry for the double comment) you shouldn't think of presentable ∞-categories as analogues of a combinatorial model category, since presentability is actually a condition that is invariant under (Quillen) equivalence. They are more akin to complete and cocomplete model categories in terms of how "hard" is to get the hypothesis.

Comment: @DenisNardin, I don't follow the second comment. Every model category is bicomplete, but certainly not Quillen equivalent to a combinatorial one. From what I understand, in order for a model category to give rise to a presentable $\infty$-category it should be Quillen equivalent to a combinatorial one, right?

Comment: Yes, that is true (although some definitions of model category require only finite limits and colimits). Maybe I am not quite precise enough, but what I wanted to convey is that being presentable is a relatively "cheap" condition on a (big) ∞-category. But we should probably have this discussion somewhere else.